What do the subscripts of orbitals represent?
During my study of atomic orbitals I found myself asking this question alot but I never received a satisfactory response. I have observed that except for p orbitals the subscripts of orbitals represent the nodes of the orbitals. But then I ran into a problem in the form of dz^2 and fz^3 orbitals. After reading @Dion Silverman's answer on What does the subscript of atomic orbital mean?
I understood that z^2 is actually a short form for z^2-(x^2+y^2) and that doubt got cleared up. But my question is why isn't the same valid for p orbitals, i.e., why don't their subscripts represent their nodes instead of representing their axis of symmetry? And is there a consistent meaning for those subscripts?

The same is valid for $p$ orbitals. One planar node is still a node.

Yeah I seem to have made a mistake in graphing the nodes. Thanks for the feedback.

They refer to the Cartesian polynomial expressions for the real spherical harmonics that express the angular dependence of the orbital. See for instance the table of such functions on Wikipedia

Pardon me if this sounds dumb but what exactly do you mean by "express the angular dependence of the orbitals". I know that the wavefunction can be represented as a product of the radial function and the angular function, and from your answer I understood that the angular function is a spherical harmonic and its representation in Cartesian form is the subscript of the orbital. But what exactly do the radial and angular functions tell us?

As for any function the coordinates define it, which means its shape if you want to draw it. Recall that $\psi(x)^*\psi(x) dx$ we interpret as defining the probability of being in range $x\to x+dx$ and similarly for $y,z$

So the radial function part tells us the probability of a particle being in the range r to r+Dr and the angular function tells us the probability of a particle being in the range θ to  θ+dθ and ϕ to ϕ+dϕ?

No. Dimensionally that can't be correct. Think what the volume element is in spherical polar coordinates.
